# Using Storm ORM, what is the preferable way to count the number of records?

Tags: python, sqlite, storm-orm

The title says it all. I tried looking through the API but couldn't find a convenient function. I've thought of a number of ways to do this. I could call `find()` and count the number of records in the result. I could use the SQLite database and execute a SELECT and  count.

Comment: I ended up using `store.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table").get_one()` There didn't seem to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Donno if you'll ever come back to this question but...

```
store.find(User).count()
```

The python console is your friend. This will give you all attributes of an object...

```
dir(store.find(User))
```

This will show you what class it returned so you can look at the api docs...

```
store.find(User).__class__
```